# Best way to ask user to crop post image to different sizes

Tags: image, uploading, image-format

I have a requirement of asking my user to create his profile images ( each of them to different proportions, for now i am allowing max 4 images and each of them user need to crop to 4 proportions)

For example Each Image user upload i am going to prompt him and ask him to crop image to 4 different proportions.

1. 750 X 400
2. 300 X 150
3. 320 X 100
4. 110 X 110

Is it a good idea to do in this way or suggest me if you have something better than this.

you can throw some insights how others are doing it.

**Note: Here user should have max 4 images and i have slider in the app.**

***PS: Goal of this is to make his profile images look all over my app beautiful.***

Comment: Cant you crop them for him?

Comment: I am Using PHP, If i do In server side the images are skewing. fi i crop them the images are becoming meaningless since a 1024X1024 image when cropped to 110X110 it becomes meaningless.

Comment: Check out IMGIX to see that will work for you http://imgix.com — really amazing tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking user to upload only one image and that too in very maximum size you want for your app. Later you can show them, 4 different area where user's image looks like. Try not to distrot image, use **masking** of images in any rectangle or elipse.

Like what we see in facebook, profile picture have different size for images and the picture we see near our post or in chat window is of different size.

We can do in this way:

1. Allow user to uplaod a picture size (750x400 PX)
2. Once uploading is done, Allow user to see the images in 4 different sizes and free to user repostion them in each sizes.
3. After that, allow them to save.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of fact, you should only ask user to upload a photo with a minimum width of 750px (or even better *as wide as possible with 750x400px as a minimum*). You can and *should* offer a crop feature, but the most important part is that your app should do all the cropping and image management.

Asking users to do it is like tellimg them to have no picture at all. Doing like you say, the most probable thing that would happen is "gee, I have to get a good picture of me, then some graphic program to create some very specific sizes that aren't even proportional. Well, guess I'll have to do this later. Or never".

In short, try to avoid any additional task for your users, make it easy and simple for them, app market is hard enough to add non needed and useless requests, just be happy if they download and engage with it!

Comment: This is an awesome response.